# How to modify items in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have an array of objects as

```
const items = [
  {name: 'Sam', amount: '455gbjsdbf394545', role: 'admin'},
  {name: 'Jane', amount: 'iwhru84252nkjnsf', role: 'user'},
  {name: 'Alf', amount: '34hjbjbsdf94334', role: 'user'},
```

The amount in the array are encrypted. And i have a function `decryptAmount()` that receives amount and returns the decrypted value `decryptAmount(amount)`

In the end, I want a new array as

```
const items = [
  {name: 'Sam', amount: 101, role: 'admin'},
  {name: 'Jane', amount: 50, role: 'user'},
  {name: 'Alf', amount: 100, role: 'user'},
]
```

How do get my intended solution?

Comment: `items.map(item => ({ ...item, amount: decryptAmount(item.amount) }))`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 2):

You can try to iterate through your array and modify your objects
So, you will have :

```
const items = [
  {name: 'Sam', amount: '455gbjsdbf394545', role: 'admin'},
  {name: 'Jane', amount: 'iwhru84252nkjnsf', role: 'user'},
  {name: 'Alf', amount: '34hjbjbsdf94334', role: 'user'}]

for(let i=0; i<items.length; i++){
    items[i].amount = decryptAmount(items[i].amount);
}
```

That should edit the amount property of objects to the decrypted value

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to use the array `map` method. This method iterates over each array element and replaces it with the returned value.

```
let items = [...];
items = items.map(item => ({
   ...item,
   amount: decryptAmount(item.amount)
}));
```

[Array Map on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

> The `map()` method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

Answer (score 1):

You can run forEach loop

```
items.forEach(item => {
  item.amount = decryptAmount(item.amount);
});
```

This will modify every amount in the array